# A4 Page Border Using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XLST for displaying Data in Tabular Format which has Header as well.

Now the problem is I am using a Oracle Tool for making Document which don't have provision for adding Border in Output Page Layout.

So is there any workaround for this problem?

I tried few XSL FO Code snippet from Antenna House which has Page Layout Master Set but I am getting blank response, I guess tool is wont support this.

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple"
    page-height="29.7cm"
    page-width="21cm"
    margin-top="0cm"
    margin-bottom="0cm"
    margin-left="2cm"
    margin-right="2cm">
    <fo:region-body margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm"/>
    <fo:region-before extent="2cm"   background-color="yellow"/>
    <fo:region-after extent="2cm"  background-color="red"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple">
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
<fo:block font-size="10mm">
'hello' in 'region-body'      
</fo:block>
</fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code so that we can see what you have tried?

Comment: I tried above XSLT Snippet which I added in XSL Snippet Element and I am using Doc Designer Tool which is Part of Oracle CPQ.

Comment: I don't know Oracle CPQ, but your sample works in AH Formatter (once I put `fo:root` around it). What do you have that works in Oracle CPQ?  An `fo:region-body` is allowed to have a border (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_region-body).  What error message do you get from Oracle CPQ?

Comment: I tried both with ```FO:ROOT``` and without. I am not getting error message as such and content which needs to be displayed is getting displayed but without Page Border. As such we don't have any in built feature which adds Page Border so that's why I am looking for workaroud.

Comment: I hope that you used `fo:root` and not `FO:ROOT`, since XML is case-sensitive. (But I do not know what Oracle CPQ uses.) You should be able to just add `border="thin solid black"` to the `fo:region-body` to generate a border.

Comment: I tried with ```fo:root```  as well but got blank document.

Comment: Put a single-cell table as the child of `fo:flow` and put everything else inside that.